# Multiple dates select datepicker for angular 2 application?

Tags: angular

I am working with angular2 and I want a datepicker which will select single date as well as multiple dates.
In my application I have a field in which I want multiple dates.
Please suggest me a datepicker which is best for my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Material2 datepicker is still being worked on but currently I'm using [md2](https://github.com/Promact/md2) which works nicely. I believe you can do date ranges on that (if that's what you mean) otherwise not sure it's a date picker you're after?

**UPDATE:-**

So I think what you need to do is use a regular datepicker like md2 and when a user clicks a date add it to an array which is linked to an `*ngFor` which displays the newly added date with an `X` next to it something like this:-

Component functions:-

```
public addNewDate(date) {
    this.dateArray.push(date);
}

public removeDate(removedDate) {
    this.dateArray = this.dateArray.filter((date: any) => {
        return removedDate !== date;
    })
}
```

Html:-

```
<md2-datepicker type="date" placeholder="Pick a date"
                [(ngModel)]="newDate"
                (ngModelChange)=addNewDate($event.target.value)>
</md2-datepicker>


<div *ngfor="let date of dateArray">
    {{date}}<span (click)="removeDate(date)">X</span>
</div>
```

Not tested the code but it's roughly how I'd do it. If you need to then use the dates to do something else you have them all in an array on your component.

Comment: My complete requirement is that I have an input field and a datepicker and if I open datepicker I will select one date and it will be seen in input field with cancel sign and if I want to add more dates I will open the dialogbox and select other date and it will also shown in input field with cancel sign and the dates I have selected previously will show selected in datepicker.

Comment: Updated my answer.